# Wp_Schedule_Event every day at specific time

Tags: cron

I write Following code to run my function every day at 16:20 ..

But I guess is the problem in code..

not working

Epoch timestamp: 1427488800

3/28/2015 1:10:00 AM

```
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'import_into_db' ) ) {
wp_schedule_event( time('1427488800'), 'daily', 'import_into_db' );

function import_into_db(){

////My code

}
add_action('wp', 'import_into_db');
}
```

Comment: The `time()` function doesn't take an input argument, try the `strtotime()` function or the `strftime()` function instead, to create custom timestamps from a string. But if you already got the timestamp, you don't need them.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

WP Cron runs, when somebody visits your website.
Thus if nobody visits, the cron never runs.

Now there are 2 solutions:

1. Disable WP Cron, use a real cron job and customize it.

https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job

2. Use a custom interval in `wp_schedule_event()`:

   ```
   function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
       $schedules['every_six_hours'] = array(
           'interval' => 21600, // Every 6 hours
           'display'  => __( 'Every 6 hours' ),
       );
       return $schedules;
   }
   add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

   //Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
   if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myprefix_cron_hook' ) ) {
       wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_six_hours', 'myprefix_cron_hook' );
   }

   ///Hook into that action that'll fire every six hours
    add_action( 'myprefix_cron_hook', 'myprefix_cron_function' );

   //create your function, that runs on cron
   function myprefix_cron_function() {
       //your function...
   }
   ```

and you can see these tuts

http://www.nextscripts.com/tutorials/wp-cron-scheduling-tasks-in-wordpress/

http://www.iceablethemes.com/optimize-wordpress-replace-wp_cron-real-cron-job/

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/

custom Wp cron

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/cron_schedules

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/16/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/

http://www.viper007bond.com/2011/12/14/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-cron-intervals/

http://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-wordpress-cron/

https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/

http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-cron-jobs-in-wordpress

cron linux

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800

[google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wp%20cron%20job%20wih%20real%20cron%20job&oq=wp%20cron%20job%20wih%20real%20cron%20job&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.21049j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=wp%20cron%20job%20with%20real%20cron%20job&spell=1)

Answer (score 32):

Instead of [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php), use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function so you can specify the time of day - it will use today's date with the time that you specify. So in your case:

```
strtotime('16:20:00'); // 4:20 PM
```

Usage in the `wp_schedule_event` function would look like this:

```
wp_schedule_event( strtotime('16:20:00'), 'daily', 'import_into_db' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, 1427488800 resolves to March 27, 2015, so your event isn't even set to start yet.

Also, bear in mind that scheduled WP events will only fire if someone hits the site at that time.

Comment: Now ,How fix? @vancoder

Answer (score 2):

This code is working for me, I believe it is closer to the original question. You want to get the UNIX time + timezone for when you want it to execute. Once the cron executes and is removed from WP, it recreates itself at the time you specify.

In the following example, I have it working for AEST (GMT+10) @ 6AM each morning. So I am scheduling it for GMT 20:00 each day.

```
if (!wp_next_scheduled('cron_name')) {
    $time = strtotime('today'); //returns today midnight
    $time = $time + 72000; //add an offset for the time of day you want, keeping in mind this is in GMT.
    wp_schedule_event($time, 'daily', 'cron_name');
}
```