# Cron job shedules replace?

Tags: plugins, php, customization, cron

I was watching this: [Wp_Schedule_Event every day at specific time](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179694/wp-schedule-event-every-day-at-specific-time) and im wondering if I do the following will it replace all my schedules?

```
function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_six_hours'] = array(
        'interval' => 21600, // Every 6 hours
        'display'  => __( 'Every 6 hours' ),
    );
    return $schedules;
}
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );
```

I have more cron jobs running but if I do this will it replace the timer? For example, I have 1 running 1 time every hour, will it be replaced? Just wondering if it will mess up the `cron_shedules`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't affect your existing scheduled Cron events, as they already have a schedule interval set. It will only add a new custom schedule interval that will be available for new ones. So long as you are adding to the `$schedules` array and returning it (which you are) then it will all be fine.

Comment: thanks alot! i took the risk and tried it anyway :P. thanks for your answer!